# the error with trigger in MySQL 5.1.63-community

Tags: mysql

I write a  trigger in MySQL 5.1.63-community , it's always note:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 ,but I run the code at navicat for mysql ,it's ok.

code here:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_sign 
AFTER insert on students
for each row
Begin
INSERT INTO sign_in(num,uptime,flag,sid)
        values(null,now(),false,NEW.sid);
end;
```

Comment: For a one-line trigger you don't need to use `BEGIN` and `END`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the trigger body contains only one statement you don't need to use `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_sign AFTER INSERT on students FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO sign_in(num,uptime,flag,sid) VALUES(null,now(),false,NEW.sid);
```

For multiple statement triggers you need to switch the delimiter:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trig_sign 
AFTER INSERT on students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sign_in(num,uptime,flag,sid)
        VALUES(null,now(),false,NEW.sid);
    -- more statements
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I also had  a  try to do it ,but MySQL server version is damn ,it don't support "delimiter",  I just find it  by my roommate's MYSQL of   MyPhpAdmin. Your code is right ! thank you very much! I have to change my mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-define `delimiter` like this:

```
delimiter ||
CREATE TRIGGER trig_sign 
AFTER insert on students
for each row
Begin
INSERT INTO sign_in(num,uptime,flag,sid)
        values(null,now(),false,NEW.sid);
end ||
delimiter;
```

Also you can see official doc about [**delimiter**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

everyone who have the some problem with me ,you can follow the code by Paul Spiegel .If it don't work  ,I think your mysql version also don't support "delimiter ",I  advise you change version.